# Why doesn't this approximation work?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, trigonometry

$$\cos{\left(\frac{2\pi}{9}\right)}$$

$$f(x) = \cos{(2\pi x)}$$

$$x = a + h$$

$$x = 0 + \frac{1}{9}$$

$$f(a+h) \quad\text{approximately is :} \quad \cos(0)-\sin(0)\cdot 2\pi \cdot \frac{1}{9}\quad \text{which is wrong...}$$

Why doesn't it work this way? Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: You need more terms in the expansion.

Comment: @MarkViola I went by the formula: $f(a+h) = f(a) + f'(a)*h$

Comment: The formula is an approximation, not an equality: $f(a+h) \approx f(a) + hf'(a)$.  The approximation is not good in this case (it doesn't exactly fail, but it's not good) because the function has substantially non-zero second derivative; colloquially, the cosine function is noticeably "curved" at $x = 0$.

Comment: If you used more terms, you would get a better estimate. With that number of terms, you would get a better estimate by expanding around $\pi/3$ instead of around $0$.

Comment: @Ian So the process of picking the right function is actually okay, I would just need to add one more ?

Comment: Yes, but that is a crude approximation that is good for very small $h$.  Here $h \approx 0.7$.  But, if we use $f(a+h)\approx f(a)+f'(a)h +\frac12 f''(a) h^2$ you'll find $\cos(2\pi/9) \approx 0.756$.  This is not a bad approximation.   If we used a fourth order approximation, we find $\cos(2\pi/9)\approx 0.766203583$ while $\cos(2\pi/9) \approx 0.766044$ to 6 decimals.

Comment: With the quadratic term retained in the expansion around zero, the error is about 0.01, which is still not spectacular but it could be worse.

Comment: @MarkViola So I can pick the same $f(x) = \cos(2x\pi)$

Comment: If you were to evaluate $f(x) = x^2$ this way, for example, you would get $f(x) \approx 0$.  That would obviously be OK for $x$ close to $0$, but would be increasingly bad as $x$ got further from $0$.  That's more or less what's happening here.  You would get a better approximation if you used the appropriate second-degree term: $f(x) \approx 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$.  This yields $f(2\pi/9) \approx 1-\frac{2\pi^2}{81} \approx 0.756$, whereas $\cos \frac{2\pi}{9} \approx 0.766$, but this too would get worse as $x$ moved away from $0$.  It just doesn't get bad as quickly as the approximation $1$ does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done all the steps of using a tangent line to approximate the value of a function, and have gotten a good approximation! .766... is not too far off from 1.

The maximum possible error of the linear approximation is $\frac12 \left[\text{max}_{c} |f''(c)|\right] (x-a)^2$

In this case $|f''|$ gets quite large at $x=0$. Specifically $f''(0) = -39.478\ldots$

Comment: So my approximation is equal to 1, if I would go one more term I would get 0.766. Do I understand correctly

Comment: https://youtu.be/3d6DsjIBzJ4

Comment: See Mark Viola's comment above: you need a degree 4 Taylor Series to get .766 . Using the Quadratic Approximation only gives you .756....